# ModuleNotFound Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller, exe

I am using:

- PyInstaller 5.3
- Python 3.9
- Windows 11

I have my directories set up like so:

```
Project
|
+ -- DoSomething
|    |
|    +-- doessomething.py
|
+ -- GUIs
     |
     +--GUI_main.py
```

The .py files contain the following code:

doessomething.py

```
def doing():
        print('Doing')
```

GUI_main.py

```
from DoSomething.doessomething import *
doing()
```

1. I have tried the following commands

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole GUIs/GUI_main.py
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole -p /path/to/DoSomething/dir GUIs/GUI_main.py
```

Where the path to DoSomething is the absolute path on my computer.

2. The working directory as the project directory
3. The Working Directory as the GUI directory

The program compiles and runs fine in PyCharm but after packaging it with PyInstaller and running it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUI_main.py," line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DoSomething'
```

Comment: have you tired using the options in here? https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search

Comment: @eroc1234 yes, I have tried all of these yet I have the same issue

Comment: please create a [example]

Comment: @Alexander I edited the post to reflect a minimal reproducible example

Comment: from which path are you running the pyinstaller command? Inside project folder?

Comment: that is not reproducible code.

Comment: @manjy I am inside my project path

Comment: @Alexander What's not reproducible about that?

Comment: Reproducible means that I can run the code myself and it will produce the same results.

Comment: @Alexander The code presented reproduces the issue for me; maybe our environments are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you're telling PyInstaller the wrong directory; you want to use `-p /path/to/Project` instead. This is because your `DoSomething` folder is *inside* the root `Project` directory. You're telling PyInstaller *where to look* for modules/packages that you try to import.

---

For a little more context...

I don't use PyCharm myself, but it would appear that it's handling something for you automatically: it's adding your top-level `Project` path to your Python Path. This means that when your code attempts to import a module, `Project` is one of the places it looks for that module name. This is the reason your code works as-is in PyCharm.

If you open a standard terminal, go to `Project`, and run `python GUIs/GUI_main.py`, you *should* find that you get an `ModuleNotFoundError`. In order to make it work, you can add the proper directory to the Python Path environment variable (for the current session) with:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/Project:$PYTHONPATH
```

After doing this, running the script directly should work. What's also neat is that PyInstaller respects your Python Path... so you can then run PyInstaller, without specifying any search folders, and it will correctly find your other Python file.

---

Sidenote: standard practice is to keep Python package/module (essentially folder/file) names all lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my structure is not the smartest. I was able to use pyinstaller without using the full path in the command. Keeping the main GUI python file in the main project folder fixes the issue. Something like this

```
ProjectFolder
|
+ -- DoSomething
|    | 
|    +-- __init__.py
|    |
|    +-- doessomething.py
|
+ -- GUIs
|    |
|    +--add_on_gui.py
|
+ GUI_main.py
```

Then in the command line in the project directory

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole GUI_main.py`

This did the trick for me.